# iOS 7 Sprite Kit in-app purchase blocks presenting a scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, 2d-games

In the setting screen of my game I offer in-app purchase for more vans player can drive in the game. If I initiate buying request, disregard if transaction fails or it has been successful, after I go back in the main menu and start the game, new Scene won't be presented (even the blank one).
Then I need to close the app(remove from memory) and open it again to everything be back on normal.
Does anyone know what can be the problem? Why does some of In-app purchase calls block presenting new scene ?

Thank you very much, I'm dealing with this problem for days.

This is the code to start the scene:

```
SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition revealWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:0.4];
    ICMyScene *newScene = [[ICMyScene alloc] initWithSize: winSize];

    [self.scene.view presentScene: newScene transition: reveal];
```

This is the code for making purchases:

```
- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:nRemoveAdsNotif object:nil userInfo:nil];

}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Transaction error" message:transaction.error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Comment: It would be a nice start if you actually posted some of your code. Perhaps starting with the bits that initiates the buying request and the code supposed to trigger the scene from the menu...

Comment: Here I edited the question. Thanks for trying to help.